# Video in an Android's WebView plays with sound, but no image with hardwareAccelerated=true

Tags: android, html, video, webview, playback

I'm trying to play a video from an HTML5 file in an Android's WebView. I have tried several solutions offered here, such as encoding the video to H.264, however, so far I only hear the sound of the video with no image.

Code:

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    String data = "index.html";
    webView.loadUrl(data);

    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.clearCache(true);
```

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Any help is apreciated, thank you.

Comment: not sure your specific issue, but my sample that I've used in a few apps is here - https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414. My guess will be either the `hardwareAccelerated` being an issue (older Android devices), or the video encoding

Comment: @Offbeatmammal thank you, your link helped solved my initial problem. 
Now, off to resolving KitKat WebView rendering issues.

Comment: great :) shall I post it as an answer so you can tick it to confirm for others?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal sure, your link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to instantiate a webview so that it is able to play video/audio on most modern Android devices I use the following `Java` code. This allows well formed HTML and appropriately encoded video content to play back reliably when using `hardwareAccelerated` in the manifest.

```
package com.offbeatmammal.android.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // load the customURL with the URL of the page you want to display
    String pageURL = "http://url/page.html";
    webView.loadUrl(pageURL);

    //String customHtml = "<html><head><title>Sample</title></head><body><p>Sample</p></body></html>";
    //webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain why this code works?